# Use @Min(0) to validate an integer encounter NumberFormatException

Tags: java, spring-boot

In Oracle's document, it says @Min is used to check "The value of the field or property must be an integer value greater than or equal to the number in the value element." I use @Min(0) to validate my form input to positive integer or zero but encounter NumberFormatException when I input 1.2. (I use Spring Boot + Thymeleaf)

What am I doing wrong?

My Code:

```
@Min(value = 0, message = "need zero or positive integer")
private int qty;
```

When I input -1, I got the message I want, but when I input 1.2, I got NumberFormatException:

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type int for property qty; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.2"
```

Comment: `1.2` is a _floating point_ value, not an _integer_.

Comment: Yes! I input 1.2 and expect @Min(0) give me an validation error message. But it shows NumberFormatException but not validation message.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate numbers like this.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.PositiveOrZero;
```

```
@NotNull(message = "Prop must be not null.")
@PositiveOrZero(message = "Prop value should zero or positive.")
private Integer prop;
```

Comment: But I need it to be an integer!!

Comment: You can use Integer instead of BigDecimal